# Count and Sum for various ranges with various columns

Tags: sql, oracle

After some help I got these commands in pl sql developer:

```
 SELECT  CASE
    WHEN t.aaa BETWEEN 1 AND 5000000 THEN '01'
    WHEN t.aaa BETWEEN 5000001 AND 7000000 THEN '02'
    WHEN t.aaa BETWEEN 7000001 AND 10000000 THEN '03'
    WHEN t.aaa BETWEEN 10000001 AND 30000000 THEN '04'
    WHEN t.aaa BETWEEN 30000001 AND 50000000 THEN '05'
    ELSE '06' END T
,count(t.bbb), sum(t.aaa)
FROM t.ccc
WHERE t.ddd IN  ('3','4','5','6','D','E','F')
AND t.zzz like '60%'
GROUP BY CASE 
   WHEN t.aaa BETWEEN 1 AND 5000000 THEN '01' 
   WHEN t.aaa BETWEEN 5000001 AND 7000000 THEN '02' 
   WHEN t.aaa BETWEEN 7000001 AND 10000000 THEN '03'
   WHEN t.aaa BETWEEN 10000001 AND 30000000 THEN '04'
   WHEN t.aaa BETWEEN 30000001 AND 50000000 THEN '05'
   ELSE '06' END order by 1;
```

The result is:

```
   T    COUNT(T.bbb)    SUM(T.aaa)
   1       1019           5519981
   2       878            8620000
   3       2250           16499000
   4       6844           4638E+11
   5       6061           691E+11
   6       915            8452192
```

So I had my Counts and Sum for various rows.  Now I want to know how can I have same rows for various columns. I mean one `COUNT(T.bbb)` and `SUM(T.aaa)` for every `t.zzz` ( with various `t.zzz`).

These result example is for same ranges in row and 2 `t.zzz`:

```
   T    COUNT(T.bbb)    SUM(T.aaa)   COUNT(T.bbb)     SUM(T.aaa)  
   1       1019          5519981       19             654321
   2       878           8620000       654            98765432
   3       2250          16499000      321            3454643
   4       6844          4638E+11      154            3213454
   5       6061          691E+11       2158           23132464
   6       915           8452192       145            341321321
```

And also I want have all the rows even the amount of `t.bbb` is "0".

Comment: Hint: `count()` and `sum()` are aggregate functions.

Comment: i could have what i want if i had the the the various rows in my pl developer view and use "select distinct" and "left join" command. but for now i cant have the row ranges in sql view. just can use "case" command. need a loop or something to count again for next t.zzz and put the result as new columns.

Comment: Again: `count()` and `sum()` are aggregate functions. Group by what you want to group by and move on.

Comment: didn't undrestand. please write an example.

Comment: There are plenty of them [in the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10592/functions003.htm). The `group by` clause is a fundamental part of SQL.

Comment: U mean different values of t.zzz?? Like as you used for '60%'??

Comment: yes mari nextt.zzz can be "61%".  jack, i saw all of group by examples. but dude i can use the group by for 1st t.zzz . as i did. what should i do for next ???. also i told befor i dont have the t rows(1,2,3,4,5). i need to count the T ranges then 'group by' by them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not exactly clear what you are trying to do but it seems like you want to `count()` and then `sum()` using some additional filtering.  If that is the case you can use a `case` statement similar to this:

```
SELECT  CASE
    WHEN t.aaa BETWEEN 1 AND 5000000 THEN '01'
    WHEN t.aaa BETWEEN 5000001 AND 7000000 THEN '02'
    WHEN t.aaa BETWEEN 7000001 AND 10000000 THEN '03'
    WHEN t.aaa BETWEEN 10000001 AND 30000000 THEN '04'
    WHEN t.aaa BETWEEN 30000001 AND 50000000 THEN '05'
    ELSE '06' END T,
  count(case when t.zzz like '60%' then t.bbb end) Count_BBB_60, 
  sum(case when t.zzz like '60%' then t.aaa end) Sum_AAA_60,
  count(case when t.zzz like '61%' then t.bbb end) Count_BBB_61,
  sum(case when t.zzz like '61%' then t.aaa end) Sum_AAA_61
FROM t.ccc
WHERE t.ddd IN  ('3','4','5','6','D','E','F')
GROUP BY CASE 
   WHEN t.aaa BETWEEN 1 AND 5000000 THEN '01' 
   WHEN t.aaa BETWEEN 5000001 AND 7000000 THEN '02' 
   WHEN t.aaa BETWEEN 7000001 AND 10000000 THEN '03'
   WHEN t.aaa BETWEEN 10000001 AND 30000000 THEN '04'
   WHEN t.aaa BETWEEN 30000001 AND 50000000 THEN '05'
   ELSE '06' END order by 1;
```

Comment: ya. i think this is the best answer for that. done . thx.